# routing error: No route matches [GET] "/users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I get this error when I try to navigate to localhost:3000/users

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNC0x.png

This is my routes.rb file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTG2G.png

I've looked at similar questions/answers on SO but they all seem to have much larger code bases. I believe this should be a simple error because I have hardly written any code besides the code generated by scaffold.

If it helps I'm following a book by Michael Hartl

problem solved thanks to Andrew Wei had to re-install the ruby stack (ruby, rails, git, gem, railsinstaller, etc.)

Comment: maybe you did something that requires you to restart the rails server, before the changes take effect.

Comment: interesting. I just restarted aptana studio and google chrome and, lo and behold, rails seems to be broken as I cannot start the server!

Comment: In the future, please post your code along with your question. It's easier than providing links.